# cakephp how to find all model name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a job to import excel file and save the data to database via cakephp, the probleme is, this application allow user to choose the table that he want to used to save the data from excel file, so i need to list all the model name, i have search through google how to get all model name but i can't find it. I just can get all the table name, but this is not enough. I must know all the model name, please help me...

I can get all the field name uses this code:

```
$this->loadModel('Person');
        $fieldsArray=$this->Person->find('all');
        $fieldsArray=Set::extract('/0/Person',$fieldsArray);
        $fieldNames=array_keys($fieldsArray[0]['Person']);
        debug($fieldNames);
```

but as you can see, i have to know the model name, i can't solve this problem, please help me..

Best regards...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$allModelNames = Configure::listObjects('model');
pr($allModelNames);
```

Note:
This only works for CakePHP1.x
For CakePHP2.x please use App::objects() instead.

Comment: Just a note that this is now deprecated in favor of App::objects http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-App.html#_objects

Comment: @Sudhir, can you please add a note that your answer works only for `CakePHP < 1.3`

Answer (score 14):

```
$Model = App::objects('Model');
pr($Model);
```

Comment: but because of lazy loading this will list only the models already loaded, not all of them